# Pumping laser for Ti:Sapphire laser

Tags: experimental-physics, laser, spectroscopy, instrument

I now own Tsunami Ti: Sapphire laser from Spectra-Physics. This laser is an ultrafast laser. Now, this is pumped by Millenia CW green laser. Apart from the output coupler problem, I am considering replacing the Millenia laser with a VerdiG-5 laser from Coherent. This CW laser is an OPSL (optically pumped semiconductor laser). Is it possible to be replaced? I am worrying that the manufacturer between Ti: Sapphire and pumping green laser are different.

https://www.laserfocusworld.com/lasers-sources/article/16551266/ultrafastlaser-pumping-opsl-has-no-green-noise

Comment: yes, standard procedure in ultrafast labs. Just follow what Gilbert said.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should be fine. Just make sure that the power is appropriate for your output coupler (or vice versa) and the beam profile (and mode diameter) is comparable to that of the Millennia.

Comment: thanks. I just have checked about the parameters such as the beam profile, turning out to be almost the same each other.

Comment: @user15181 great! Enjoy!